# I am trying to submit JSON data using ajax to the mvc 5 controller method But i am receiving null or some times the controllers doesn't get hit.I

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

the ajax code works fine  but I am unable to receive it in controller . I think the problem is with the type of argument which i use to receive json data in controller

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "@Url.Action("Create","Questions")",
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/Questions/Create',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {
                option: JSON.stringify(options)
            }
        })
```

here is enter code here my method code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(List<Options> option)
        {




            return View();
        }
```

The data which i need to submit is list of options with a check box with every option that is either true or false

```
0: {option: "option 2", isOption: false}
1: {option: "option 3", isOption: false}
2: {option: "option 2", isOption: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery Ajax Method

```
 var opt = [{ option: "option 2", isOption: false }, { option: "option 3", isOption: false }, { option: "option 2", isOption: true }];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Questions/Create',
            data: JSON.stringify({ option: opt }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

In Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Create(List<Options> option)
   {
    // Actions
       return Json(option);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much  i was looking for solution for one and a half day. You saved me ,it worked for me

Comment: One more thing can i send two ajax calls on one button click

Comment: @Ummar Yes you can send two ajax calls same like that